# Как получить количество показов фразы за год в API яндекс директа?

Tags: json, яндекс-директ

Отправляю на https://api-sandbox.direct.yandex.ru/live/v4/json/ вот такой запрос:

```
data = {
    "method": "CreateNewForecast",
    "startDate": "2020-02-30",
    "endDate": "2020-04-03",
    "param": {
        "Phrases":
            phrase
        ,
        "GeoID": [
            149
        ],
        "Currency": "RUB",
    },
    "token": TOKEN_YM,
    "locale": "ru",
}
```

И не зависимо от значений внутри startDate и endDate возвращает данные за месяц.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?